# Show complete array in JQuery auto-complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user types in autocomplete box,  I  pass this character to server, get a  response, and show this response as autocomplete list.

Every thing is fine when I get same the results. For example:- If I type 'a' then I pass 'a' to server;  and if server respond with '*car*','*cat*','*man*', Then this list show as auto complete, But if server respond with '*hell*','*boy*','*lion*', then it's not showing in autocomplete drop down, because response doesn't have 'a' character.

How can I show those results which don't have matched character ?

Here is sample code for auto-complete code:

```
$(function() {
        var availableTutorials = [
           "cat",
           "car",
           "boy",
           "hell",
        ];
        $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
           source: availableTutorials
        });
     });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12a16nbb/)

Comment: isn't the purpose of auto-compete to show only relative data?

Comment: I dont understand your problem , It is working fine

Comment: @Yasmin his problem is clear ,

Comment: In short i want to show all of array data when user types. I don't want to show relative data.

Comment: You mean to say, whatsoever user type, you want to display all the data, is it ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @MokshShah Yes, Because every time i get result from server. I dont want to add a validation on this( Which is by-default by jquery)

Comment: @ZeRubeus I want to show on type, Not on click of something.

Comment: If it is not required to filter data, then why do you use autocomplete plugin?
or if you still want to go with autocomplete then you can pass `""` `empty string` to server so it will always return all the records

Comment: on type you need to write your owen js code who do this

Comment: Like in this example. If we type a then it show 2 fields, One of them doesn't have a, But still showing. http://jsfiddle.net/chetanpatil/a1buhpo8/9/

Comment: It shows parent category of that item, its now showing `all items`? what are you looking for? be clear, all items or something like that in above fiddle you have mentioned?

Comment: Like it's showing all category without having that character, I want to show complete array.

Answer (score 0):

Try the new HTML5 [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag

For ex.:

```
<label for="default">Pick from a color list</label>
<input type="text" id="default" list="colors" placeholder="e.g.Black">

<datalist id="colors">
    <option value="Black">
    <option value="Grey">
    <option value="Yellow">
    <option value="Orange">
    <option value="Pink">
</datalist>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkqtas52/1/)

**Update:**

And [example with AJAX](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/jKnzG) calls.

Comment: Is this what  OP looking for? have you read question properly?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what he is looking for. Tthis can be implemented AJAX calls. See in Matt West's CodePen site--> insert the answer

Comment: No, it's not that i want. In your example if i type 'b' it will show only black, I want all data.

Comment: Of course, because "grey" does not contains letter "b"...but you can show all list item, with arrow!